# Does react native release build use a bundler?

Tags: react-native

I looked around in XCode and it indeed seems that appdelegate is the same and hence it really runs a locally a server where it server the js bundle. Is that correct, or I'm missing somehting? (I hope I am, since it's way easier to have the JS bundle as one of the assets - where did I miss it?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app is running locally, the bundle is loaded over a node instance. This allows you to do things like Chrome debugging, hot reloading, and all that cool stuff.

When you build the app in release mode, react-native generates a static js bundle. Then, this bundle is run in a local js environment on your device, so it's not running over a server or anything like that.

You can see more information about how to point to the static bundle on [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#3-configure-app-to-use-static-bundle).